# Safari push notification frequency limit

Tags: push-notification, safari, service-worker, user-experience

What is the maximum number of the push notifications in Safari browser per a minute?

it seems like when I want to send some notification to users at a minute, the safari browser automatically removes the subscription object.

what is the limitation?

compared with other browsers and so on.